# Are custom component configuration variables not supported in the new release templates?

Tags: powershell, ms-release-management, dsc

Release Management always had the concept of "components", which are units of deployment that can be independently configured in the pipeline. Each component could have a number of stage-specific configuration variables, that could be configured in the component itself, like this:

[image]

Then, in the template instance, these could be set to different values depending on the stage:

[image]

But on the vNext components, required for the new vNext templates that use PowerShell DSC or Chef, these configuration variables don't exist anymore:

[image]

Are stage-specific configuration variables not supported anymore in RM? Am I responsible for setting these variables myself using PowerShell inside the configuration script now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vNext components don't support tokenized configuration files. I think the idea is that setting the application's configurations are going to be handled via DSC, instead of via RM. I noticed the same thing when I was playing with DSC deployments.

Old-style components still support tokenized configuration files.

Comment: So the idea is to change the web.config files properties with a DSC resource, or something along those lines?

Comment: You can either use the configuration script where the DSC variables are defined, or have the variables defined in the components tab as you just figured. These variables will be available to your PS/DSC script that you run via the Deploy using PS action.